# Espresso custom matcher

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-espresso

trying to create custom matcher that will accept any matchers. I have now:

```
fun isDisplayed(id: Int): Boolean {
        fun ViewInteraction.isDisplayed(): Boolean {
            try {
                check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
                return true
            } catch (e: NoMatchingViewException) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withContentDescription(id)).isDisplayed()
    }
```

But my goal to create some kind of generic matcher that will accept all matchers similar to:

```
fun isDisplayed(matcher: Matcher): Boolean {
        fun ViewInteraction.isDisplayed(): Boolean {
            try {
                check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()))
                return true
            } catch (e: NoMatchingViewException) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return Espresso.onView(matchers).isDisplayed()
    }
```

Do I need to create custom matcher or generics in order to achieve what I want?

Comment: I do not understand what is your benefit of using so much code if you can just do `onView(...).check(matches(isDisplayed()))`. Please explain.

Comment: @ror I don't want to fail assertion. I'm writing e2e tests and would like to do certain actions if element displayed or not. If I do your way it will just do `matches` and will fail or pass it based on it

Comment: Understood. Then I'd say "why not" to your 2nd sample, except that you need to use Matcher<View> instead of Matcher in your argument.

Comment: Thank you. It worked :) . I thought I need somehow create a custom matcher for that

Comment: @IlyaG. Can you give me idea how to write this same code in java??